# Android studio creating live templates

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

I am creating a simple live template to show an AlertDialog in AS,
snippet:

[image]

However, the Edit variables option is now inactive, even after I have selected the language type. Any help with this?

Previously I was able to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable in Live templates is specified between '$' characters. I noticed that, in your example, 
$className is specified instead of ***$className$***. Just use the ***$className$***(ends wit $) instead of *$className* and the "*Edit Variables*" button should become active.